# What does 0. mean in Python?

Tags: python

I am a beginner python user. 
Can someone explain what does this code means?

```
harvest["year"] = harvest.index.year
harvest["DM"] = harvest["N"] = 0.
```

`harvest`, `year`, `DM` and `N` are data and data variables. What does `0.` mean here?

Answer (score 9):

```
>>> type(0)
<class 'int'>
>>> type(0.)
<class 'float'>
```

It just ensures that the result, while still being "zero", is a [float instead of an int](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-complex).

Comment: This is the correct answer. It's pretty standard to have any whole number followed by a single decimal point to define it is a float, not just `0.`.

Comment: in python 2 this used to be a common way to avoid floor division (not for 0 of course)

Comment: This was specially useful in python 2, where integer division was the norm. `3/2` resulted in `1`, while `3./2` resulted in `1.5`.